# Macro to compare dates from different file

Tags: excel, vba

I am an old man trying to compare dates from two different files in Excel.
My code is:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 7

IF Data_for_Processing.xls (“SOLARLOG”). Cells (i,”A”).Value = Day_Conversion_chart.xls (Sheet1).Cells (i+2, “B”) Then

Cells(7+I, “B”)=”Equal”
Else: Cells(7+i, “B”) = “NotEQ”

End If

Next i
```

Will anyone help?

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend following @simoco 's advice - Reading the documentation will provide the tools for solving future problems and give you the basics.  As well as that, I would recommend using vba help.  And another very useful tool for trying commands could be recording macros and analyzing them later on the editor.

So, first you need the code to be inside a macro.  It will look like this (I chose the name TestMacro):

```
  Sub TestMacro()
   'Code here.
  End sub
```

You should take into account that when your macro is running, it does so from the sheet you are working in, so any partial references to cells, etc. will refer to the book you are in and the sheet you are in when you run the macro.  It is possible to select another sheet or book, and if you do so manually or on the code, references will be applied on that selected book or sheet.

What I call partial references here are those that read simply "ThisCell" instead of "ThisBook.ThisSheet.ThisCell".  I would say that using partial references, though, is appropriate in a vast majority of cases.

The way your code is organized, be careful to run it from the workbook where you want the data to be in the end, let's say, in your 'main' workbook, so that the final values will be written there..

Another comment:  whenever you want to use another file, this file must be open (as far as I know), while you are using it.  In your code, you don't open any file, so the macro will not work if you don't open ALL referenced workbooks manually prior to running the macro.

When you want to reference something inside something, you mostly use ".".  Please read the documentation - You will get a better idea of how this works.  For this example:

Book.Sheet.Cell.Value is the structure you are using.

A book can be referenced as Workbooks("Name.xls") if it is open.

A sheet or worksheet can be referenced as Sheets("Name") or Worksheets("Name"), and also with numbers, like Sheets(1) or Worksheets(1).  The differences can be seen on vba editor help.  I chose Sheets(...) for your example.

Be careful with the symbols.  I guess this was probably my problem, but I have to mention it just in case:  When I copied your code, instead of double quotes (""), I got something different, that Excel would not recognize.  If for any reason you are using different symbols, Excel might not understand.

A cell can be referenced in various ways too.  The Range object is used extensively, and if you want to use "A1", "C44", etc., it's probably better to go for it.  I like using Cells(,) as you did, when possible.  As far as I know, this works nice with numbers (Cells(1,2), for example), which may be very convenient too.  I kept this on your code, changing "A" and "B" and writing 1 and 2, respectively.

With all these changes incorporated:

Comments:

```
'NOTICE THAT ALL WORKBOOKS MUST BE OPEN.
'["A"] changed to [1]
'[Sheet1] changed to [1]
'["B"] changed to [2]
'Data_for_Processing.xls(“SOLARLOG”).Cells(i, 1).Value
'becomes Workbooks("Data_for_Processing.xls").Sheets(“SOLARLOG”).Cells(i,1).Value
'Day_Conversion_chart.xls(1).Cells(i + 2, 2).Value
'becomes Workbooks("Day_Conversion_chart.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(i+2,2).Value
'["B"] changed to [2]
```

And one possible solution:

```
Sub TestMacro()

  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 7  

    If Workbooks("Data_for_Processing.xls").Sheets("SOLARLOG").Cells(i, 1).Value _
    = Workbooks("Day_Conversion_chart.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(i + 2, 2).Value Then

      Cells(7 + i, 2) = "Equal"
    Else: Cells(7 + i, 2) = "NotEQ"

    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

This worked on my Excel example - I hope it is of some help.

Regards.